# Checking if an input is formatted correctly in Python 3

Tags: python

so I've been assigned an assignment (obviously) to check if an input that a user has entered is formatted correctly, in the way AA99AAA (where A is a letter and 9 is a number from 0 to 9). So for the first character in the input, it would have to be a letter or python would return some sort of error and so on, you get the idea. I've got no clue where to start with this, I've tried looking around and haven't found anything - I guess I just don't know what it is I'm looking for. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You may use regex. Check: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html . and +1 since you didn't asked for solution but only the head-start

Comment: regex may be little tough, alternatively you may iterate over your string and check the ascii value of each character is within the range of ascii values of`0-9` and `A` (or what ever character you need)

Comment: I'll give the regex way a try but if that proves too difficult, how would you go about doing it the ASCII way? Just use some sort of loop and check it each time?

Comment: Yes. A loop over string and the check within it. Use `ord(ch)` to find the ascii value of `ch`. If string is supposed to be of fixed length, use `len(string)`  to find the length of string. If you want to check first character of string is `A`, use `string[0] == A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you could split the string into 3 parts (the first group of letters, the numbers, and then the second group of letters). Then you can use `s.isalpha()` and `s.isnumeric()`.

For example:

```
while True:
    c=input('Password: ')
    if len(c)==7 and c[:2].isalpha() and c[2:4].isnumeric() and c[4:].isalpha():
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
print('Valid input')
```

Comment: I wasn't aware you could do :2 or 4: like that. It sorted out my formatting and it now works for me. Thanks!

Comment: `[:2]` and `[4:]` are splices to either end of the list. They're useful to save time when writing code.

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide more information regarding the question, is the example you have provided the format you are attempting to match? `AA99AAA`, so 2-alpha, 2-numeric, 3-alpha?

There are two approaches off the top of my head you could take here, one would be to utilize regular expressions to match on something like `[\w]{2}[\d]{2}[\w]{3}`, alternatively you could iterate through the string (recall that strings are character arrays).

For this approach you would have to generate substrings to isolate parts you are interested in. So..

```
for c in user_input[0:2]:
    if c.isdigit:
        print('Invalid Input')
for c in user_input[3:5]:
...
...
```

There are definitely more pythonic ways to approach this but this should be enough information to help you formalize a solution.

Comment: It is not good to throw away the solution over someone when the OP just wants a head-start and wants to learn programming. Learning programming the hard way makes people a better programmer :)

Comment: Yes this is the format that I am trying to match. I see what you are doing here, that helps a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I finally did it! After about an hour...

So I used [] formatting and .isdigit/.isalpha to check each part of the code, like recommended above, however I did it in a slightly different way:

```
while True:
regNo = input("Registration number:")
if len(regNo) != 7:
    print("Invalid Registration Number! Please try again")
elif regNo[:2].isdigit():
    print("Invalid Registration Number! Please try again!")
elif regNo[2:4].isalpha():
    print("Invalid Registration Number! Please try again!")
elif regNo[4:].isdigit():
    print("Invalid Registration Number! Please try again!")
else:
    break
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else who stumbles across this problem!